# How to find keylength of SSH RSA keys using java

Tags: java, ssh, rsa, jsch

I am using JSCH API to find length of RSA SSH keys .

I use the following code to do that:

```
KeyPairRSA KPR = (KeyPairRSA) KeyPairRSA.load(jsch, keypath);
System.out.println("size " +KPR.getKeySize());
```

This returns me always length 1024 .I think its bug with API itself.
Can anyone please tell me how to find length of RSA/DSA SSH keys?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Why do you think this isn't doing what you think it is?

Answer (score 3):

I'm the author of JSch.

It is a bug or the incompleteness of KeyPair* classes.
They had been just introduced for the key-pair generation purposes.
But, in our internal development version, KeyPair* classes have been overhauled, and
that method has worked well.

# This is off-topic, but we have added the support for Putty's private key format, as a bonus! :-)

Anyway, the fix will be available in the next release, and if you can't wait for it,
replace KeyPairRSA#getKeySize() with the following,

```
public int getKeySize(){
  return (new java.math.BigInteger(n_array)).bitLength();
}
```